# HTML5 WebSocket: Client's messages are buffered in Google Chrome 22

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, websocket

I am writing a very simple chat application based on the [HTML5 WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) technology where the server (implemented using [node.js WS](https://github.com/einaros/ws)) keeps track of all the connected users and broadcasts each received message. The client on the other hand, connects to the server and according to user's actions, sends messages to the server.

The problem that I am observing is that unless the server sends a message to the client after opening the connection, all messages sent from the client running on Google Chrome get buffered until several messages have been sent. Once the buffer is full, all messages are sent at once. This creates a very unresponsive chat experience for the end user.

The fix that I found was to add single `ws.send("Hello Client:" + clientId);` after opening the connection on the server side, but *I am not sure why this is necessary?* Below you can find snippet from my client and server components, but the entire source code is available at [ChatMate git project](https://github.com/zkhalapyan/chatmate).

**Server Code:**

```
wsServer.on('connection', function (ws) {
    var clientId = nextClientId += 1;
    clients[clientId] = ws;
    log("Accepted connection from client " + clientId + ".");

    //The fix: If you emit this initial message from the server, then
    //all of client's messages will be cached. 
    ws.send("Hello Client: " + clientId);

    ws.on('message', function (message) {
        log("Received message: " + message);
        var id;
        for (id in clients ) {
            if (clients.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                if (parseInt(id, 10) !== clientId) {
                    clients[id].send(message);
                }
            }

        }
    });
});
```

**Client Code**:

```
function WebSocketTest() {
    "use strict";
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://DOMAIN:8080/");

    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log("Connection is open.");
        //This message will not be sent if the server does not send 
        //a message first.
        ws.send("Client Message.");
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log("Message is received: " + e.data);
    };

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295929/java-websocket-server-outputstream-not-flushing) helps?

Comment: @maenu, I am not actually writing a server that handle's the WS handshake. I think the issue is from Chrome's implementation of WebSocket API.